# Use image in Highcharts credits

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is it possible to use an image for the Highcharts `credits` option? I'm hoping to add a small logo instead of text. I've tried setting the background-image using the `style` property and passing an image tag instead of text to the `text` property, but the image never appears.

```
credits: {
    text: '',
    href: 'http://www.example.com',
    style: {
        backgroundImage: 'url(http://placehold.it/50x20)'
    }
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vQa3C/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see a way using the chart credits options, but there is nothing to stop you adding a logo using the renderer:

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
chart.renderer.image('http://placehold.it/50x20',350,360,50,20).add();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yVTmG/

Comment: Bonus points: Can we somehow add a link to that image as well?